# converting a row-wise csv file to json in python

Tags: python, json, csv

I have this input file which I want to convert to a json.

1.] As you can see the key:value are spread in row wise fashion rather than column wise.

2.] Each has a "Comments" key , whose value is spread across different rows for each of the elements. As some users might write lengthy comments.

```
key,values

heading,A
Title,1
ID,12
Owner,John
Status,Active
Comments,"Im just pissed "
        ,"off from your service"
,
heading,B
Title,2
ID,21
Owner,Von
Status,Active
Comments,"Service is  "
        ,"really great"
        ,"I just enjoyed my weekend"
,
heading,C
Title,3
ID,31
Owner,Jesse
Status,Active
Comments,"Service"
        ,"needs to be"
        ,"improved"
```

Output

```
{{'heading':'A','Title':1,'ID':12,'Owner':'John','Status':'Active', "Comments":"Im just pissed off from your service"},
{....}, 
{.....}}
```

Since my csv file has "key":"values" in row wise fashion, I really am clueless as to how to convert it into a json.

=====what I tried=====

```
f = open( 'csv_sample.csv', 'rU' )
reader = csv.DictReader( f, fieldnames = ( "key","value" ))
for i in reader:
    print i


{'value': 'values', 'key': 'key'}
{'value': 'A', 'key': 'heading'}
{'value': '1', 'key': 'Title'}
{'value': '12', 'key': 'ID'}
{'value': 'John', 'key': 'Owner'}
{'value': 'Active', 'key': 'Status'}
```

As you can see , that's not what I want. Please help

Comment: do you want the result to be {'key':'values','heading': 'A' ...

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** : Maybe try something along these lines:

```
import json

def headingGen(lines):
    newHeading = {}
    for line in lines:
        try:
            k, v = line.strip('\n').split(',', 1)
            v = v.strip('"')
            if not k and not v:
                yield newHeading
                newHeading = {}
            elif not k.strip():
                newHeading[prevk] = newHeading[prevk] + v
            else:
                prevk = k
                newHeading[k] = v
        except Exception as e:
            print("I had a problem at line "+line+" : "+str(e))
    yield newHeading


def file_to_json(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as fh:
        next(fh)
        next(fh)
        return json.dumps(list(headingGen(fh)))
```

Comment: Ive updated the post : Each has a "Comments" key , whose value is spread across different rows for each of the elements. As some users might write lengthy comments.

Comment: Thanks Dain, but Im getting "too many values to unpack" error on "k, v = line.strip('\n').split(',')
"

Comment: If it is because there is a comma in a comment, try with `k, v = line.strip('\n').split(',', 1)`

Comment: Im getting this now ---- UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 6: invalid start byte

Comment: The problem is with these kind of comments (with commas in between them), and almost all comments are of this format --"For particular reasons, we sometimes may need to shut down our services"  [ i.e. ", , ," format comments ]. This is giving rise to --"too many values to unpack" error

Comment: Did you try with `split(',', 1)` ? I forgot to add it in my edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96792/discussion-between-shalini-and-daindwarf).

Comment: Hi Dain thats solved but not this one -- "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 6: invalid start byte

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses Python's list comprehension to provide a functional style alternative to other (also nice) answers using an imperative style.  I like this style because it separates different aspects of the problem nicely.

Nested list comprehensions construct the result by first splitting the input into sections and creating a dictionary out of each section by splitting it into items using a regular expression and applying a function split_item() to each item to  finally get the key/value pairs.

The source data is read by sections for improved memory efficiency.

```
import re
import json

# Define a regular expression splitting a section into items.
# Each newline which is not followed by whitespace splits.
splitter = re.compile(r'\n(?!\s)')

def section_generator(f):
    # Generator reading a single section from the input file in each iteration.
    # The sections are separated by a comma on a separate line.
    section = ''
    for line in f:
        if line == ',\n':
            yield section
            section = ''
        else:
            section += line
    yield section

def split_item(item):
    # Convert the the item including "key,value" into a key/value pair.
    key, value = item.split(',', 1)
    if value.startswith('"'):
        # Convert multiline quoted string to unquoted single line.
        value = ''.join(line.strip().lstrip(',').strip('"')
                        for line in value.strip().splitlines())
    elif value.isdigit():
        # Convert numeric value to int.
        value = int(value)
    return key, value

with open('csv_sample.csv', 'rU') as f:
    # Ignore the "header" (skip everything until the empty line is found).
    for line in f:
        if line == '\n':
            break

    # Construct the resulting list of dictionaries using list comprehensions.
    result = [dict(split_item(item) for item in splitter.split(section) if item)
              for section in section_generator(f)]

print json.dumps(result)
```

Comment: Did you try it before editting?  It was correct.  It used list comprehension.  Please ask before editting if you don't understand it.

Comment: I reverted to my original version.  List comprehension is more efficient than loops and I believe also more readable (when you get used to it).

Comment: I just turned the key/value split and convertion into a separate function.  Hope this improves readability.

Comment: As the example was changed to include multiline quoted strings in 'Comments' I updated the code to handle that correctly, trying to stick to using list comprehension in order to provide alternative to other answers here (some of which I also like).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def convert_to_json(fname):
    result = []
    rec = {}
    with open(fname) as f:
        for l in f:
            if not l.strip() or l.startswith('key'):
                continue

            if l.startswith(','):
                result.append(rec)
                rec = {}
            else:
                k, v = l.strip().split(',')
                if k.strip():
                    try:
                        rec[k] = int(v)
                    except:
                        rec[k] = v.strip('"')
                else:
                    rec['Comments'] += v.strip('"')
    result.append(rec)
    return result

print convert_to_json('./csv_sample.csv')
```

output:

```
[{'Status': 'Active', 'Title': 1, 'Comments': 'Im just pissed off from your service', 'heading': 'A', 'Owner': 'John', 'ID': 12}, {'Status': 'Active', 'Title': 2, 'Comments': 'Service is  really greatI just enjoyed my weekend', 'heading': 'B', 'Owner': 'Von', 'ID': 21}, {'Status': 'Active', 'Title': 3, 'Comments': 'Serviceneeds to beimproved', 'heading': 'C', 'Owner': 'Jesse', 'ID': 31}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a straightforward conversion, so we need to specify it exactly:

- input file is a csv file with 2 columns named `key` and `values`
- a record is composed of different lines, defining the key and the value of a mapping
- the key `heading` denotes the start of a record
- a blank key is a continuation line - its value should be added to the previous value
- if the value of a continuation line does not start with a separator and if the preceding value does not end with a separator, a space is inserted (separators are space, tab, dot, comma and `-`)
- the `heading` field cannot have a continuation line - this allows a simpler decoding

The code can be:

```
with open('csv_sample.csv') as fd
    rd = csv.DictReader(fd)
    rec = None
    lastkey = None
    sep = ' \t,.-'
    for row in rd:
        # print row
        key = row['key'].strip()
        if key == 'heading':
            if rec is not None:
                # process previous record
                print json.dumps(rec)
            rec = { key: row['values'] }
        elif key == '': # continuation line
            if (rec[lastkey][-1] in sep) or (row['values'] in sep):
                rec[lastkey] += row['values']
            else:
                rec[lastkey] += ' ' + row['values']
        else:
            # normal field: add it to rec and store key
            rec[key] = row['values']
            lastkey = key
    # process last record
    if rec is not None:
        print json.dumps(rec)
```

You can easily convert it to a generator by changing the `print json.dumps(rec)` by `yield json.dumps(rec)`

With your example, it gives:

```
{"Status": "Active", "Title": "1", "Comments": "Im just pissed off from your service", "heading": "A", "Owner": "John", "ID": "12"}
{"Status": "Active", "Title": "2", "Comments": "Service is  really greatI just enjoyed my weekend", "heading": "B", "Owner": "Von", "ID": "21"}
{"Status": "Active", "Title": "3", "Comments": "Serviceneeds to beimproved", "heading": "C", "Owner": "Jesse", "ID": "31"}
```

As this code uses the csv module it is *by construction* immune to commas in comments.

Comment: LINE 7 :   KeyError: 'key'

Comment: @shalini: I cannot reproduce under Python 2.7 . What is your Python version and what is your OS ? Or could you show your real input since I can see in a comment to another answer an UnicodeDecodeError

Comment: Could you uncomment the `print row` line and show what is displayed before the error?